# Quotient rule or algebra mistake

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to derive this

$$ f(x)=\frac{6}{1+2e^{-5x}}$$

and getting this

$$ f'(x)=\frac{0(1+2e^{-5x})-6(0-10e^{-5x})}{(1+2e^{-5x})^2}$$

$$=\frac{60e^{-5x}}{(1+2e^{-5x})^2}$$

But the answer I get when checking on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+6%2F%281%2B2e%5E%28-5x%29%29) is

$$f'(x)=\frac{60e^{5x}}{(2e^{5x}+2)^2}$$

I don't understand how this works. How do the exponents for e become positive all of a sudden, and where does the +2 in the denominator come from?

Comment: They both are the same....:) .It's a nice exercise: take your expression, simplify it and show it's the same as in WA.

Comment: Oops! The expression *must* have in the denominator $\,(e^{5x}+2)^2\,$...check this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seemed to have copied the equation from Wolfram wrong (there is no $2$ in front of the $e^{5x}$). To see how the two expressions are the same multiply the top and bottom of the fraction by $(e^{5x})^2$.

Comment: Oh, the 2 sneaked it's way in there. Thanks to both for verifying and guiding. :)